# CSV value population of HTML Template custom fields in Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, csv

I want to create a large amount of posts in wordpress with only a few words different per page for an experiment I am currently conducting.
The variables will be changed in the following areas:
- Post URL
- Meta Title
- Meta Description
- HTML content template.

My first thought was to create a CSV file with all the variables per page, 1 row = 1 page.

There was a way to do it with Gravity Forms till v. 1.9 but seems to be impossible now.

Any idea how I could solve this problem?

Comment: Are you willing to write your own code (this is a code site after all) or are you after something to do it for you?

Comment: Id like some ideas on tools, options, workarounds on how to do it... Not really a coder myself

Comment: You could use Custom Fields: https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

Comment: I only ask as http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for your question - this is place more for code :)